# Arduino IR send ASCII, wait, send, read

Tags: arduino

I need help building a "simple" arduino code to transmit and receive an IR signal.

I tried several codes available on the Internet, but nothing that fits my Logarex electricity meter.
Like:
http://tunn.us/arduino/landisgyr.php
https://github.com/prophetmaster/landisgyre350

Communication is done by IEC 62056-21.
I'm trying to send a handshake to my electricity meter
0x2F, 0x3F, 0x21.0x0D, 0x0A
Then a request for data
0x06.0x30.0x35.0x30.0x0D, 0x0A
Income
Unfortunately, I can't get any information. Would it be easy to send a handshake over the IR transmitter, then request the data and then start receiving it on the IR receiver?
Do I need to communicate on baud 300 to shake hands, then 9600 in the next part and receive 9600 in IR RX?

```
The output should be something like this on an arduino serial monitor.

Baudrate: 300 bps, 7 bits, parity even, 1 stop bit
Send:     /?!<CR><LF>         (wake-up and sign-on)
Receive:  /XXX5YYYYY<CR><LF>  (XXX is the manufacturer ID; YYYYY is the meter ID; 5 is the new baudrate = 9600 bps)
Send:     <ACK>050<CR><LF>    (send ack; reading mode)
Baudrate: 9600 bps, 7 bits, parity even, 1 stop bit
Received: C.1(201236731.0(01:39 25-08-18)
      1.8.1(0004398506*Wh)
      1.8.2(0000000000*Wh)
      1.8.3(0008198809*Wh)
      1.8.4(0000000000*Wh)
      1.8.5(0000000000*Wh)
      1.8(0012597315*Wh)
      2.8(0000000000*Wh)
      !
      D
```

Thank you all for your help, I am a beginner and I have no experience with IR.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using arduino uno, the standard library does not support the 7E1 required for the initial query. To do this, you have to write your own uart driver.

you need to write the receiving part, I share it in terms of giving ideas.

```
//Description video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s4W6sOT0mU
typedef struct uconfig
{ 
  uint32_t  baud;
  uint8_t  _UBRR0H;
  uint8_t  _UBRR0L;
  uint8_t  _UCSR0B;
  uint8_t  _UCSR0C;
} baud_registers;

/*
 * How can i calculate _UBRROH and _UBRR0L. Here is the cpp script.
 * You need to check the atmega328p datasheet to understand
 * 
#include <iostream>
#define BAUDRATE 300
#define _UBRR (((16000000 / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)
int main()
{
  int msb= ((_UBRR) & 0xF00);
  int lsb = ((_UBRR) & 0xFF);
  if(msb>256)
  {
      msb= msb>>8;
  }
  std::cout<<"msb: " << msb;
  std::cout<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"lsb : "<<lsb;

}
 * 
 * 
 */
static const uconfig  baud_table[]= {
  {300,0x0D,0x04,0x18,0x24},
};

int uart_init(uint32_t baudRate_u32)
{
  int status=0;
  uint8_t i=0;
  for( i=0; i< sizeof(baud_table)/sizeof(baud_table[0]); i++)
   {
    if(baud_table[i].baud == baudRate_u32)
    {
       break;
    }
   }

   if( i < sizeof(baud_table)/sizeof(baud_table[0])) {
    UBRR0H=baud_table[i]._UBRR0H;
    UBRR0L=baud_table[i]._UBRR0L;
    UCSR0B=baud_table[i]._UCSR0B;
    UCSR0C=baud_table[i]._UCSR0C;
    status=1;

   }
   return status;

}

void USART_transmit( unsigned char data ) {
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
}

void setup() {
  while(!uart_init(300));
}

void loop() {
  USART_transmit('a');
  delay(1000);
}
```

Also , In my thesis I worked on reading electricity meters. I did the reading using Arduino mega.